# Position text by pixel rather than alignment

Tags: image, javafx, text, label, alignment

I have created my own button and label backgrounds in Photoshop, but I am finding it difficult to position text correctly due to large borders.  Every reference I am finding aligns text with something like `object.setAlignment(Pos.BASELINE_LEFT)`, but this actually overlaps the border of my buttons and labels.  I believe I need to be able to position it by the pixel distance from the edge, but I do not know how this is done.

[image]

One way that would work I suppose is to put the label background inside an ImageView, put that ImageView inside a StackPane, and put a GridPane in that StackPane as well, on top of the ImageView.  I would then put a TextField inside the GridPane at column: 1, row: 0 and set a column constraint on the first column to align my text where I want it, but there has to be a better way than this.

```
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(new Image("C:\\file.png"));
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    TextField textField = new TextField("TextField text");
    gridPane.add(textField, 1, 0);
    ColumnConstraints constraints = new ColumnConstraints(10);
    gridPane.getColumnConstraints().add(constraints);
    stackPane.getChildren().addAll(imageView, gridPane);
```

Comment: Do you have a single image file for the entire background, or separate background for each control? You may want to style your controls using CSS, either recreating the backgrounds using the appropriate gradients, or setting the `-fx-background-image` property. See [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#region].

Comment: I think I would prefer that the empty spaces of the UI absorb the differences between screen resolutions so that I can maintain the intended height x width ratio in the buttons and labels.  I believe that to do this I cannot have the entire background as one image.

Comment: So why not set the image as the background of the appropriate control (button, label, etc.)?